# How to divert flow of control by using toggle button of another activity from existing activity

Tags: android, android-intent, toggle, togglebutton

I have made an application with 4 activities named Activity1.xml,Activity2.xml,Activity3.xml,Activity4.xml now.in activity1 i have put a "toggle Button" with "yes" and "no" ,Now my first activity also have "next" button,when pressed the "activity2.xml" will be opened,it also have "next" button,Now the point is that when the next button of "activity2" is pressed it will check "toggleButton" of "activity1",and if it is "yes" it should go to "activity3" otherwise "activity4"...I have tried as below but its not working please help me ,actually i have no idea how yo do it so please:

**Activity1.java**

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent intent = new Intent(Calculator_1Activity.this, Calculator2.class);
                intent.putExtra("toggleBtn", tg.isChecked());
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

in **activity2.java**

```
  btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if(val==true){
                    Intent iq=new Intent(Calculator2.this,Deposit.class);
                    startActivity(iq);
                }
                else{
                    Intent ir= new Intent(Calculator2.this,Calculator_3Activity.class);
                    startActivity(ir);
                }

        }
    });
```

still not working

i have put pictures so that it will be better understandable..

**Activity1.xml**
[image]
**Activity2**
[image]
**Activity3**
[image]
**Activity4**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use an Boolean field to check if ToggleButton is Clicked or not on Next button click from other Activity like Activity1,Actitity2 ,etc...

Use `Intent.putExtra` for sending status of ToggleButton to other Activity as :

```
public static boolean status=false;
tg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          if (isChecked) {
             Intent ia = new Intent(Calculator_1Activity.this,Calculator2.class);
             status=true;
             ia.putExtra("tg_status", status); //<< send button status here
             startActivity(ia);
          } else {
              // The toggle is disabled
             Intent ib = new Intent(Calculator_1Activity.this,Calculator2.class);
             status=false;
             ia.putExtra("tg_status", status); //<< send button status here
             startActivity(ib);
           }
    }
});
```

use `tg_status` to check button is clicked or not before moving to other Activity.

and you can directly access it as `Calculator_1Activity.status` in other Activities

Comment: can you please tell me how to use it in activity2 @ its "next" button please thanking you

Comment: have u try it as on next button click `if(Calculator_1Activity.status){}else{}` in activity2

Comment: I ahve tried ur code but its only working on "if" not in "else":                                                                        if(Calculator_1Activity.status=true){
     Intent ix=new Intent(Calculator2.this,Deposit.class);
     startActivity(ix);
    }
    else{
     Intent iy = new Intent(Calculator2.this,Calculator_3Activity.class);
     startActivity(iy);
    }

Comment: @jimmycool : use if(Calculator_1Activity.status==true) instead Calculator_1Activity.status=true

Answer (score 0):

when opening activity 2 from activity 1, send the value of toggle button as a boolean( checked or not )  along with it in the intent extra ... and simply in activity 2 do the course of action based on value recieved from activity 1 ...

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
   intent.putExtras("toggleBtn", toggleButton.isChecked());
```

In activity2/NextActivity get the value of toggle btn in oncreate via

```
   boolean val= getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("toggleBtn");
```

based on val start activity3 or activity4 in the next btn click listener

Comment: i have edited my question ,and add your code but project is not working...please help

Comment: In activity1 when starting activity2 send toggleBtn state via above intent/Extra and in activity2 next button click listener use that value .. no need of the checklistener in activity1 code , after sending the value to activity2 and storing it in a boolean value use that boolean in the next btn listener of activity 2 .. post code of activity 2 next btn click listener

Comment: I have edited my code as per ur suggestion ,but its not working ,please check it brother.

Comment: what happens? what do you mean by not working, does it always open Deposit.class or Calculator_1Activity.class.. or are you getting an error :) ... and could you please post code of how you are filling boolean "val" in Activity2

Comment: Could you please post code of how you are filling boolean "val" in Activity2 .. post code of oncreate of activity2

Comment: baboo-i have edited my question but still not working yaar...:(